# NHibernate with existing database and not using a designer to create mappings

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

First - I am new to NHibernate.

I am creating an application in VS 2010 using C# and MVC3 for a client. The client has a huge database with hundreds of tables and the application needs to read data from only a couple of them.

When the client installs the application on the webserver he/she should specify the connection string to the database and also the names of the tables data should be read from (in web.config or similar), nothing more. The columns of the tables the app will read data from is known (basically it's just id and a few more fields), but not the name of the tables are not known (the name of the tables has the format "CompanynameTablename") and should be specified by the client.

Is this even possible with NHibernate? If so - how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible and if I got correctly your question, you have to create a highly configurable mapping: in order to do so you can prefer the N[H 3.x mapping by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777898/docs-examples-for-nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-code) solution instead of standard hbm xml files. With this you can put in the cfg file just the names of the table and write the mapping strategy entirely in code. Anyway if you are new in using NH, you will probably exercise some more standard solution just to train yourself before implementing the final solution.
Take care anyway, NH is an OR/M and you will receive benefits just if you use it for map associations and collections, identity maps, automatic persistence and so on. Consider also using a Micro Orm as [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) would probably help you better.